# Reference to "Sensible Susan" in E. Nesbit's New Treasure Seekers?

Tags: identification-request, e-nesbit

E. Nesbit's *The New Treasure Seekers* contains what appears to be a reference to another book titled *Sensible Susan*:

> So at the next farm, which was half hidden by trees, like the picture
> at the beginning of Sensible Susan, we tied the pony to the gate-post
> and knocked at the door.

I can't find another reference, though from context it would appear Ms. Nesbit thought it would be common knowledge to the children of 1904.  Is it a primer or a picture-book?  Google seems to think I'm asking about *Narnia* or *Swallows and Amazons*, both of which were published well after *The New Treasure Seekers*.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the Ngrams hint, I eventually located an illustrated 1903 edition of [*Tales from Maria Edgeworth*](https://archive.org/details/talesfrommariaededge). [Page 91](https://archive.org/details/talesfrommariaededge/page/90/mode/2up), near the beginning of the story "[Simple Susan](https://archive.org/details/talesfrommariaededge/page/86/mode/2up)", contains an illustration by Hugh Thomson matching the description of a "farm half hidden by trees" in *The New Treasure Seekers*:

[image: A man on a horse wearing a black hat is talking to a young woman wearing a polka-dot dress standing on some steps under a tree. In the background a cottage is half-screened by trees. A caption reads, "The gentleman asked her how many miles it was".]

This story had been in publication since 1796, though the illustration is newer.  Given how well it matches the quotation, I'm willing to guess that this was what Nesbit was referring to.  Thanks to Rand al'Thor for the Ngrams search hint and to Tsundoku for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

I have been unable to find a book entitled *Sensible Susan* in the catalogues of the [British Library](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?ct=facet&fctN=facet_rtype&fctV=books&rfnGrp=1&rfnGrpCounter=1&query=any%2Ccontains%2CSensible%20Susan&fn=search&indx=1&search_scope=LSCOP-ALL&dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A(BLCONTENT)&vl(2084770704UI0)=any&vid=BLVU1&ct=search&institution=BL&tab=local_tab&vl(freeText0)=Sensible%20Susan&dstmp=1640641175466&fromDL), [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3ASensible+Susan&qt=advanced&dblist=638) or the [Library of Congress](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg1=Sensible+Susan&argType1=all&searchCode1=KTIL&searchType=2&combine2=and&searchArg2=&argType2=all&searchCode2=GKEY&combine3=and&searchArg3=&argType3=all&searchCode3=GKEY&year=1521-2021&fromYear=&toYear=&location=all&place=all&type=all&language=all&recCount=25). Due to the alliteration in the name, it is also possible that "Sensible Susan" refers to a stereotype that figures in a specific book and that the characters in Nesbit's *The New Treasure Seekers* are referring to the book by means of that character rather than the book's title.

Alice Nuttall's article [The Susan: The Story of an Archetype, and Why We Need Her](https://bookriot.com/the-susan-archetype-childrens-literature/) (19 November 2018) seems to support the assumption that "sensible Susan" may be a stereotype (emphasis mine):

> Are you the eldest girl in a classic children’s novel? Are you extremely sensible and organised? Do you have a younger sister who’s a bit of a tomboy, and who all the readers love more? Then you might be a Susan.
>
> **If you’re reading children’s literature from a certain era, a Susan is bound to pop up sooner or later.** She will be the second child, and the oldest girl. She will always be the group mum, keeping her siblings in line and standing in for their actual mum, who is always absent and sometimes dead. She will make sure that her brothers and sister are fed, clothed, and have somewhere warm to sleep. They will not appreciate her for doing so.

Unfortunately, the examples given in that article come from more recent books than *The New Treasure Seekers*:

- Susan Walker from Arthur Ransome's [*Swallows and Amazons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallows_and_Amazons) (1930),
- [Susan Pevensie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Pevensie) from C. S. Lewis's *The Chronicles of Narnia* (1950–1956),
- several characters whose name isn't even Susan but who are "Susans in nature, if not in name", including … Dora Bastable from E. Nesbit's *The Story of the Treasure Seekers*.

Arthur Ransome's [*The Picts and the Martyrs*](https://www.fadedpage.com/books/20180869/html.php) (1943) at one point refers to Susan Walker as "sensible Susan" (emphasis mine):

> Dorothea read her letter aloud, a pleasant cheerful letter from their mother, hoping that they would both have a happy time at Beckfoot, hoping that the new boat was ready, and that they would presently be teaching her and their father how to sail, urging them not to take risks at first, and saying that she was really rather glad that while **that sensible Susan** was not there to look after things they would be sleeping in a house and not miles from anywhere in tents on an island or up in the hills.

Later on, she is also referred to as "the careful Susan" (emphasis mine):

> Then, remembering **the careful Susan**, Dorothea began to plan her housekeeping, and set out, on another page, to make lists of food for separate meals, breakfasts, dinners and suppers.

The stereotype is also mentioned in Maria Nikolajeva's book chapter "The Identification Fallacy: Perspective and Subjectivity in Children's Literature" in [*Telling Children's Stories: Narrative Theory and Children's Literature*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Telling_Children_s_Stories/QWQqDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+Susan%22++character&pg=PA193&printsec=frontcover), edited by Mike Cadden. University of Nebraska Press, 2010):

> Instead of portraying one complex character, the author splits the personality between several actors, getting the brave Peter, the sensible Susan, the treacherous Edmund, and the honest Lucy rather than one character possessing many and sometimes contradictory features.

(The list obviously refers to characters from *The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe*, but the discussion is more general.)

In a snippet view of [*Delphi Complete Novels of Frances Hodgson Burnett (Illustrated)*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Delphi_Complete_Novels_of_Frances_Hodgso/mraRBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+Susan%22++character&pg=PT6587&printsec=frontcover) (Delphi Classics, 2014), I found:

> The reader learns to love sensible Susan Sowerby, Dickon, the animalcharmer, Ben Weatherstaff, and the dear, pert little robin.

Susan Sowerby is a character from [*The Secret Garden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Garden), which was serialised in 1910–1911, several years after *The New Treasure Seekers* (1904).

Below are a few examples of "sensible Susan" from before 1904.

In ["Uncle Sam's Daughters" in *The Plantation*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/The_Plantation/85dQAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+susan%22&pg=PT90&printsec=frontcover) (1872):

> There is the sound, sensible Susan, who with her clear-cut face, watchful, moderate eye and well-chosen dress fills up the corners at hop or ball, where conversation does not prevail. Susan is too sound and practical not to know that marriage is her just and fitting career; and to know, too, within a fraction, how much love and income will be requisite to make the aforesaid marriage move upon well-oiled wheels.

In [*The Haunted Room* by Charlotte Maria Tucker](https://www.google.de/books/edition/The_haunted_room_by_A_L_O_E/zv4BAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+susan%22&pg=PA32&printsec=frontcover) (1876):

> "On windy nights, I suppose," said the sensible Susan. "I've heard a sighing, and a rattling, and a howling even here in Summer Villa."

In [*Miss Priscilla Hunter, and My Daughter Susan*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Miss_Priscilla_Hunter_and_My_Daughter_Su/qYI2AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+susan%22&pg=RA1-PA9&printsec=frontcover) (1879):

> "What a blessed comfort a quiet, domestic, elderly daughter must be; fashioned like that sensible Susan of Mrs. Carleton's!"
> This I said to my husband one evening, (…)

In [*Marriage à-la-mode*, Volume 2](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Marriage_%C3%A0_la_mode/9vABAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+susan%22&pg=PA81&printsec=frontcover) (1880):

> I never thought he would have been attracted by any of my girls, except my sensible Susan.

In [*After many days; or The turning point in James Power's life*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/After_many_days_or_The_turning_point_in/BhUCAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sensible+susan%22&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover) (1882):

> Thus sensible Susan found work for her brother-in-law.

Comment: But if it's just a stereotype, then how come they refer to "the picture at the beginning of Sensible Susan"? Surely that's a specific story. FWIW, [Google Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sensible+Susan%2CSensible+Susan&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csensible%20Susan%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csensible%20Susan%3B%2Cc1) for "sensible Susan" (results start around 1860) and "Sensible Susan" (no results).

Comment: @Randal'Thor "it is possible that (...) the characters in Nesbit's *The New Treasure* Seekers are referring to the book by means of that character rather than the book's title". If the title can't be found in neither the British Library nor the Library of Congress, two copyright libraries, then it is entirely possible that the title is fictional.

Comment: I'm afraid it must be that Nesbit was describing a book by something other than its title (a character named Susan who is sensible, for example).  Using Google Books to look at matches for "sensible susan" (without quotes) has turned up some intriguing possibilities but nothing so far.

Comment: Google books shows a few 19C references to "Sensible Susan" [as something of a trope](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sensible+susan%22&biw=1370&bih=662&sxsrf=AOaemvL_ib0BddfBtaCYsxjMNEiy6G901A%3A1640734566668&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1870%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1903&tbm=bks).